# Referencing two or more JSON tables in Android with PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I currently have a php script which returns a JSON encoded COUNT(*) from two tables:

```
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once 'db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all ratings from different tables
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS data1 FROM table1") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all ratings
// ratings node
$response["ratings"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $rating = array();
    $rating["data1"] = $row["data1"];

    // push single rating into final response array
    array_push($response["ratings"], $rating);
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS data2 FROM table2") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $rating = array();
    $rating["data2"] = $row["data2"];

    // push single rating into final response array
    array_push($response["ratings"], $rating);
}


// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

}

I am receiving the JSON output online:

```
{"ratings":[{"data1":"3"},{"data2":"4"}]}
```

And can confirm that there are no problems via http://jsonlint.com/

I am currently able to reference the 1st piece of data from data1, but I am getting an error message for data2:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for data2
```

Here is my JSON code:

```
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        // ambil data dari Json database
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jResult = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ratings");

            for(int i=0;i<jResult.length();i++){
                JSONObject object = jResult.getJSONObject(i);
                text_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                text_2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);

                //get an output on the screen
                int count1 = object.getInt("data1");
                text_1.append(count1+"\t\t"+"\n");
                int count2 = object.getInt("data2");
                text_2.append(count2+"\t\t"+"\n");


            }
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

I know I am not being efficient in the coding, so if anyone has any suggestions to streamline it, I'd be more than grateful.

Also, I am a fan of books for learning, but can't find any books which teach Android, JSON & MySql, if anyone would like to start one, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting that exception is that you have two json objects in an array, each of which has 1 data (either data1 or data2, not both).  So when you request data2 on the object without it, it can't find it.  Possible solutions (depending on what you're really looking for):

1)Use optInt to get the value.  This way it won't throw an exception on missing data.

2)Make sure the server pushed both values in a single object, rather than an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL queries, just add

> count(*) AS table1data

and

> count(*) AS table2data

this way at least, you can access them separately. Secondly, I'm not sure if this output you are getting is a valid json. Just tried this on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it says its not valid. Try to fix this thing as well. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: That seems a perfect solution! I am getting the result from table1data displayed, however I am getting an error message suggesting there is an error with my JSON coding:

`07-27 11:26:29.903    1735-1735/com.example.android.help2 E/log_tag﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for table2data`

I will post my JSON code to see if that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I just ran the code through your suggestion @Faraz and I got the following error response:  

Parse error on line 5:
...e1data": "3"    }][    {        "tab
---------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'

This is alien to me...

Comment: You have steered me in the right direction, but I am now experiencing an error parsing the data from the second set of results. I have updated all my findings. Your help is greatly appreciated.